# How to sort by multiple fields on dynamodb (any workaround)?

Tags: java, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I see the limitation of dynamodb with sorting
is there any work around to sort by multiple fields, also I need the pagination(because someone can say that i can sort it in the java code for example)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to achieve sorting by any attribute of an item in DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64132338/how-to-achieve-sorting-by-any-attribute-of-an-item-in-dynamodb)

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple sort keys using Local Secondary Indexes

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html

DynamoDB supports pagination, which is also supported through every DynamoDB SDK

Comment: How I can do a sort like this
sort by field1 asc,field2 desc, field3 asc ?

what I see in the link is that I can sort by one field only which is the sort ke right ?